# How do you start a pkg from command line?

Tags: pkg-file

How do you start a pkg from command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `open`, the command-line equivalent of double-clicking a file.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, not needed to extract but open it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
sudo installer -pkg ~/yourdirectory/packagename.pkg -target ~/Applications/
```

OR

```
installer -pkg ~/yourdirectory/packagename.pkg -target ~/Applications/
```

Using the following line in sudoers to skip password:

```
jinith ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```